# Date range report in PHP using MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606704/how-make-reports-with-specific-range-of-dates-in-mysql). I need to generate a PHP report using multiple variables from my database between a date range.

Here's what I have so far :

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#date_range").submit(function(){
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:".weekly_concession.php?" + new Date().getTime(),
            dataType:"text",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend:function(){
              $("#loading").show();
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#report_result").append(response);
                $("#loading").hide();
            } 
          })
          return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My data range form

```
<div align="center">
<form name="date_range" id="date_range" method="post" style="width: 454px" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Start Date : </legend>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="start" id="datepicker"/>
<legend>End Date : </legend>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="end" id="datepicker2"/>
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" name="click" >
<i class="icon icon-print icon-white"></i> 
Run Report</button>
</fieldset>
</form></div>
<br><br>
```

My Results table

```
<div align="center">
  <table id="date_range" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><table width="300" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="product_box">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#EAF0FF" class="column-light">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#EAF0FF" class="column-light"><strong> Sales: </strong></td>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#EAF0FF" class="column-light"><strong>Sale Price Total:</strong></td>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#EAF0FF" class="column-light"><strong>Cost Price Total:</strong></td>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#EAF0FF" class="column-light"><strong>Margin:</strong></td>
              </tr>
        <tr>
      <td align="center" class="column-light"><img src="images/spacer.png" width="140" height="1" /></td>
          <td align="center" class="column-light"><img src="images/spacer.png" width="110" height="1" /></td>
          <td align="center" class="column-light"><img src="images/spacer.png" width="110" height="1" /></td>
          <td align="center" class="column-light"><img src="images/spacer.png" width="110" height="1" /></td>
          <td align="center" class="column-light"><img src="images/spacer.png" width="110" height="1" /></td>
           </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" class="column-light"><strong>Bawtry</strong></td>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" class="column-light"><strong>
```

One of many SELECT statements:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE 
shop_order_day AND shop_order_month AND shop_order_year BETWEEN 'start' and 'end' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry' AND shop_order_field_to_update LIKE '%con%' ORDER BY shop_order_id DESC ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$bawtry_sales = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $bawtry_sales ?>
          </strong></td>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" class="column-light"><?php
```

...

I'm having problems making this work so that I can select the results of my query between shop_order_day, shop_order_month and shop_order_year using the dates chosen within the above form, i.e. 2014-03-09 - 2014-03-16.

So my question is what do I need to change to make either the SELECT statement correct or the Javascript functional?

Any help would be great - sorry if this is a little convoluted.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help.

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: @tadman Thanks I'll have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be wanting this query.

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM shop_orders 
 WHERE DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
       BETWEEN 'start' and 'end' 
   AND /* the other stuff in your query */
```

But you should know that this is grossly inefficient at searching. You'd be much better off with a `shop_order_date` column of type `DATE` with an index on it and the following query pattern:

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM shop_orders 
 WHERE shop_order_date BETWEEN 'start' and 'end' 
   AND /* the other stuff in your query */
```

Comment: Thanks for the amended SELECT statement. My HTML form action doesn't seem to be working. I enter the dates in the form boxes and click the 'Run report' button and it just returns to the original URL with no change? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your SQL statement I would say the problem is combination of the SQL keywords you want to use and your table structure. Instead of using separate columns for day, month and year you should consider use a single datetime column type. That way you will be able to use standard SQL functions that operate on date and time values.

Also. BETWEEN is best used with data types that are numbers. So, you could convert the date to a timestamp ... but why complicate things?

Set $start and $end to ISO standard dates - YYYY-MM-DD. Then:

SELECT * 
FROM shop_orders 
WHERE 
   shop_order_date >= '$start' 
   AND shop_order_date <= '$end'
   AND ...